# Magento Search leading to a redirect loop

Tags: magento, loops, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7 . Recently on the front end if I perform any search it leads to homepage or nothing loads at all saying "This webpage has a redirect loop"

I tried clearing cache via ftp but it did not solve the issue.

Some of them had posted to clear browser cookies which did not fix the issue either.

Thanks
Abhi

Comment: reindex may fix the issue ...

Comment: @Asifhhh it does not fix the issue. Clearing the session folder fixes it for a while then the same thing repeats.